# React Element not re-rendering on setState when state is passed

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple dark/light theme toggle to my website. In my base App.tsx I've implemented the state I use:

```
const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState("light");
```

I pass that "colorScheme" variable as a prop to every other element. The theme toggle is contained in a header element, so I also pass the "setColorScheme" function to header as a prop. Within Header.tsx, the code triggered when the toggle is clicked is:

```
setColorScheme(s => s === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
```

Within every specific element, I set the color scheme like so:

```
<ElementName className={"element_name element_name_"+colorScheme}/>
```

I have all the css for styling the component contained in the class "element_name", and then all relevant color data is contained in "element_name_light" or "element_name_dark".

When the toggle in the header is clicked, a re-render is triggered for the main body of the app, and for the header. But all of the other elements do not re-render. If I navigate to another element, the re-render happens and the color scheme appears as intended.

Attached is a gif of this happening.

[image: Gif of Described Behavior]

I'm still learning React, so I'm sure it's something obvious I'm missing. I would appreciate any tips anyone can provide! Thanks

One note: I am using react functionally, rather than implementing classes for each component.

Comment: can you share the code of how are you calling the components(especially the ones not re-rendering) and the props passed to them?

Comment: For example, in App.tsx, I would create the Contribute component (the one shown in the gif) like `<Contribute colorScheme={colorScheme}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell exactly what mistake you made since you haven't shared your code. But I can tell you the root mistake is not using React's context API. This will allow you to hold the color scheme and the toggle function as a global state and import them into every component via the `useContext` hook.

Here's an example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-lhwstv?file=color-scheme-ctx.tsx

Here's the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

---

Note: I'm using typescript, if you're using plain javascript just remove the type declarations and the generic typings `<Type>`.

You start by creating the context and giving a default value:

```
type ColorScheme = 'light' | 'dark';
type Props = { colorScheme: ColorScheme; toggleColorScheme: () => void };

export const ColorSchemeCtx = createContext<Props>({
  colorScheme: 'light',
  toggleColorScheme: () => {},
});
```

I like to then create a provider component for organization.

```
export const ColorSchemeCtxProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState<ColorScheme>('light');
  function toggleColorScheme() {
    setColorScheme((s) => (s === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'));
  }
  return (
    <ColorSchemeCtx.Provider value={{ colorScheme, toggleColorScheme }}>
      {children}
    </ColorSchemeCtx.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then wrap all components that need the context - probably just put it at the highest level possible.

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ColorSchemeCtxProvider>
      <App />
    </ColorSchemeCtxProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Now any component can get both the color scheme and / or the toggle function with `useContext`

```
export default function App() {
  const { colorScheme, toggleColorScheme } = useContext(ColorSchemeCtx);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>The color scheme is: {colorScheme}</p>
      <button onClick={toggleColorScheme}>TOGGLE</button>
      <CompOne />
      <CompTwo />
      <CompThree />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function CompOne() {
  const { colorScheme } = useContext(ColorSchemeCtx);
  return <div className={'comp-one ' + colorScheme}></div>;
}
```